# UITextField decimal pad show dot instead of comma

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikeyboard

How to show . instead of , symbol for decimal pad?

I found a few solution with using NSNumberFormatter, replacing string on the fly and extension of `UIEnglishTextField`, which should return localised textfield.

No of these solutions worked for me.

I mean for sure I can transform string, but is there a way to display right dot symbol.

Comment: AFAIK You can't. This is defined by the users device's region settings. That's a user's choice. The user has to go to Settings > General > Language & Region > Region and select the desired region and probably the language as well.

Comment: This controlled by the locale of the device. Are you saying that you have a device whose locale uses a comma and you don’t want to honor the user’s preference and override it with a dot/period/full-stop? Generally we always want user input to honor the device preferences.

Comment: got it thanks! probably it's better to use nsnumber solution then

Answer (score 1):

It's out of topic, but this code works for me (**SWIFT 5**):

```
extension String {
    static let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    var doubleValue: Double? {
        String.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = "."
        if let result =  String.numberFormatter.number(from: self) {
            return result.doubleValue
        } else {
            String.numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
            if let result = String.numberFormatter.number(from: self) {
                return result.doubleValue
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```